# Unable to login to default account after creating new account in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, login-screen, useradd, cassandra

I was trying to install cassandra in my local machine following [this article](http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/run-single-node-cassandra-cluster-ubuntu-16-04/)

I created new group and user using the following commands as suggested in the article.

```
root@ubuntu:~# groupadd cassandra
root@ubuntu:~# useradd -d /home/cassandra -s /bin/bash -m -g cassandra cassandra

root@ubuntu:~# grep cassandra /etc/passwd
cassandra:x:1000:1000::/home/cassandra:/bin/bash
```

Now on restarting the machine I could see cassandra and my old user in the login page. I am able to login to cassandra user but not into my old account. When I login , black screen is flashed and login page is displayed again.

**EDIT:**
I am not able to do any sudo actions from terminal as cassandra user. When I try root password it is saying password is incorrect. On entering the password for 'cassandra' user, I am getting ***cassandra is not in the sudoers file*** error.

```
cassandra@Sharun-UbuntuBox:~$ sudo passwd sharun
[sudo] password for cassandra: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for cassandra: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for cassandra: 
'cassandra is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

**Edit2:** I am able to login from terminal and these are the permissions

```
cassandra@Sharun-UbuntuBox:~$ su sharun
Password: 
sharun@Sharun-UbuntuBox:/home/cassandra$ getent passwd {sharun,cassandra}
sharun:x:1000:1000:Sharun,,,:/home/sharun:/bin/bash
cassandra:x:1001:1001::/home/cassandra:/bin/bash
sharun@Sharun-UbuntuBox:/home/cassandra$ ls -alh /home/
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root      root      4.0K Sep 11 15:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root      root      4.0K Aug 30 23:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 30 cassandra cassandra 4.0K Sep 11 18:02 cassandra
drwxr-xr-x 33 sharun    cassandra 4.0K Sep 11 17:59 sharun
```

**Edit 3:** I had followed the remaining commands in that article before restarting the machine:

```
[From the article]   ... You can correct the ownerships for the files and set proper environment variables to run this application smoothly.

    root@ubuntu:/home/cassandra# export CASSANDRA_HOME=/home/cassandra
    root@ubuntu:/home/cassandra# export PATH=$PATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
    root@ubuntu:/home/cassandra# chown -R cassandra.cassandra .
```

May be I have messed up the commands. Any way to undo these?

Comment: Can you login with the user `sharun` in a terminal with `su - sharun`? Also check the UIDs of the two users with `getent passwd {sharun,cassandra}` and the access rights of the homedirectories `ls -alh /home/`.

Comment: @Thomas please see my edit

Comment: What else have you entered on the command line. The group ownership of the homedirectory of user `sharun` is cassandra which shouldn't be. Any other things you have run `chown`, `chgrp` or `chmod` against?

Comment: @Thomas Edited the question

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `undo` command, so one would have to know what exactly happened. It might be save to run `sudo chown -R sharun:1000 /home/sharun`, as it seems some `chgrp` or `chown` command was run against that diretory and it may be the source of the problem.